# Modify regex to take h:mm time format in addition of hh:mm

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have this regex

> ^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$

and it validates this time format: `hh:mm AM|am|PM|pm`, for example `04:25 pm`, `11:20 am`

How do I make `4:25 pm` (no `0` before `4`) be also valid? in other word make `h:mm` be valid time format in addition of `hh:mm`
Please explain so I can understand what you do. Thanks!

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact` with `"h:mm tt"`. Implement your own validator. Do it [as it should be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624800/swedish-ssn-regular-expression-reject-users-under-a-specific-age/32625321#32625321). Regex is not your friend with datetime validation.

Comment: Are you interested in a proper (non-regex) approach? If yes, post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$
```

Comment: Why not `^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$`?

Comment: please explain the whole regex, break it into each piece, could you?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding | stands for OR So if you enter 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  OR 10,11,12 OR 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09 the time part is correct. Also you may know, [1-9] means one of digits from 1 to 9.

Comment: @Gildor why not, very good.  I just typed what it came to my mind .

Comment: @RezaAghaei Heelo Reza can you make am/pm be case insensitive, in other word it will accept: AM, Am, am, aM and same for PM

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding `^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s([aA]|[pP])[mM]$`

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding What was the result of test? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex way to write a DateTime validation in MVC app:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This value is required!")]
[MyValidateTime]
public string TimeValue { get; set; }
```

And here is the `MyValidateTime` code:

```
public class MyValidateTime: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {                 
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact((string)value, new[] { "hh:mm tt", "h:mm tt" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("Correct time formats: 01:00 AM or 1:00 AM");
    }
}
```

Here, the allowed time formats are:

- **hh:mm tt** (*01:00 AM*)
- **h:mm tt** (*1:00 AM*)

See more [DateTime formats at *Custom Date and Time Format Strings* MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)